# 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/random-number-generator-baa - Forbidden

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create npm reactjs component library. I have been working through all the steps but stuck at npm publish.

Please see the below error screenshot for which I am unable to find a solution on google after trying more than an hour(The error message is not that accurate IMHO or maybe I am not able to catch it

403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/random-number-generator-baa - Forbidden
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiwOb.png)

Comment: Are you logged in `npm`? What does `npm whoami` prints?

Comment: yes I logged in npm , npm whoami is prints akkushwaha53

Comment: You may have needed to verify your email address after creating your npmjs.org account.